# unity 2D player movement parameters do not exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've managed to make a little top down shooter now I'm going over animations. I have followed a couple tutorials by pixelnest.io but strangly I'm getting an error saying "parameter 'moveRight' does not exist. animation in unity is completely new to me and have been trying to read up as much as I can. any suggestions to fix the animation so it plays when I move right? below are some pictures and my code.

[image]

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class playerMove : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float maxSpeed = 5f;
Animator animator;
bool isRight;

void Awake(){
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update(){
    Vector3 posMove = transform.position;
    Vector3 velocityH = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * maxSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    //this is just test a before i add it to the right movement
    animator.SetBool ("moveRight", isRight);


    Vector3 velocityV = new Vector3 (0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * maxSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    posMove += velocityH + velocityV;
    transform.position = posMove;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is  because you don't have a boolean called "moveRight" in your animator.
Look at the first screenshot you posted. In the bottom left corner, you've declared a single boolean named "isRight".

While using `Animator.SetBool(yourBool, boolValue)`, you first parameter you need to pass is the name of the boolean declared in the animator (in this case, it's "isRight").

Change the following line of code in your script

Change this line

```
animator.SetBool ("moveRight", isRight);
```

to read

```
animator.SetBool ("isRight", isRight);
```